# DBDesigner 4.0.5.6 unique constraint

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I need to set a `UNIQUE` constraint for a column in the logical schema (not in the code).

You can set columns of a table as AI (auto increment) and also as NN (not null) but there seems to be no possibility to set the column as `UNIQUE`.

I tried to find it in the documentation of `DBDesigner` as well, but the only thing I found was "unique index" which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: The only way to set a column as you want is to use a Unique Index. Sometimes it's also known as the Primary Key of the table, but not always.

Comment: For my understanding a unique index only helps you to find tuples faster - it does not prevent duplicate entries, doesn't it?

Comment: It does. If you try to add a row which would contain the same unique key it can't add it to the index. If part fails, all fails.